# Aspect only working for classes on the package where the Aspect class resides

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I am trying to use AOP to log entry/exit of methods.However I am only able to log the entry/exit of methods that are part of the package where the Aspect class resides.I am unable to log the methods in the other packages.Please Help.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.dave.school.student..*(..))")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint)
    {
        System.out.println("Before::");
        System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + "/" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
    }


    @Before("execution(* com.dave.school.teachers..*(..))")
    public void before1(JoinPoint joinPoint) //doesn't work
    {
        System.out.println("Before::");
        System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + "/" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut ="execution(* com.dave.school.student..*(..))",returning = "result")
    public void after(JoinPoint joinPoint,Object result) throws JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println("After::");
        System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getName());
        ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
        String r=objectMapper.writeValueAsString(result);
        System.out.println("Result is ::" + r );
    }
}
```

Here is my spring boot app:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.dave.school"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.dave.school"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.dave.school"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.dave.school"})
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What package is your Spring Boot application in.

Comment: student package.

Comment: And does it scan other packages as well? Also it will only apply to spring managed beans. So it will not work for entities (as spring doesn't control those).

Comment: yes it scans other packages .I've declared that class in teachers package as a component.

Comment: It is recommended to place your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in a toplevel package and not a subpackage. Can you please add the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class and also add `package` information to what you have posted here.

Comment: I'm using multiple modules in my project. I've kept the application class where my rest controller reside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195456/discussion-between-m-deinum-and-rock11).

Comment: yeah sure let's talk in chat.

Comment: If there is no typo in your aspect's pointcuts (wrong package names) this definitely is a Spring configuration issue. The aspect looks okay. BTW, you are having problems with package names but you don't provide the package names for application and aspect in your code snippets and also no sample classes (also with package names) you expect to be intercepted. This is kind of counter-productive, of all things you just omit the crucial bits of information. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: what was the solution to your problem?